Upgrade dominance in distribution to almost sure in a new probability space
If we have two stochastic process (they are defined in the same probability space) $(X_t)_t$ and $(Y_t)_t$. We have for every $t\geq 0$, $X_t \leq Y_t$ a.s. Now for every $t\geq 0$, we have $Y_t\overset{(d)}{=}Z_t$. I am wondering can we construct a new probability space where we can have for every $t$, $X_t\leq Z_t$ a.s under the new probability measure?
Update for clarifying what my question is: Here I just want to substitute the upper bound for $X_t$ from $Y_t$ to $Z_t$.

What is this $n$ you mention twice?

Assuming by $n$ you meant $t$, I note there is a big difference between $P[X_t\leq Y_t]=1$ for all $t\in [0,\infty)$, and $P[X_t\leq Y_t \quad \forall t\in [0, \infty)]=1$. The way it is written does not make clear which is the assumption. Of course, even if that were clarified, I'm not sure I would understand what you are asking.

@Will sorry, there should be no $n$. I deleted them.

@Michael Here it should be the first case you write. I just want to substitute the upper bound for $X_t$ from $Y_t$ to $Z_t$. However, here $Z_t$ only has the same distribution as $Y_t$. I assume we can’t just replace the upper bound to $Z_t$?

Define $X \in {0,1}$ equally likely. Define $X_1=Y_1=X$, $X_2=Y_2=1-X$, $Z_1=1-X$, $Z_2=X$. Then $X_i\leq Y_i$ surely for all $i\in{1,2}$, and $Y_i$ has the same distribution as $Z_i$ for all $i \in {1,2}$ (since all distributions are $Bern(1/2)$). But $${X_1\leq Z_1}\cap{X_2\leq Z_2}={X\leq 1-X}\cap{1-X\leq X}=\phi$$

@Michael I know I can’t just substitute $Y_t$ with $Z_t$. But what I mean is if we can construct a new probability space in which we can make such substitution.

What do you mean by "construct a new probability space"? What is the assumption regarding the new random variables $X, Y, Z$? Note that if we are just changing the probability measure from $P$ to $\tilde{P}$ my example is a counter-example because we cannot have $\tilde{P}[X_1\leq Z_1]=1$ and $\tilde{P}[X_2\leq Z_2]=1$ if ${X_1\leq Z_1}\cap{X_2\leq Z_2}=\phi$.

It sounds like you are trying to keep the same $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$, so the functions $X_i:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $Z_i:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are always the same, but just change $P:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow[0,1]$ to some other measure $\tilde{P}:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow[0,1]$. As in my comment above, the answer is no.
Counter-example: Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be any probability space that contains a binary-valued random variable $B:\Omega\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ that has a $Bern(1/2)$ distribution, so
$$P[B=0]=P[B=1]=1/2$$
Define $X_i:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $Y_i:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $Z_i:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ for $i \in \{1,2\}$ by
\begin{align}
&X_1=Y_1 = B\\
&X_2 = Y_2 = 1-B\\
&Z_1 = 1-B\\
&Z_2=B
\end{align}
It is clear that the requirements you specified are upheld:

$X_i\leq Y_i$ surely for $i \in \{1,2\}$ (since $X_i=Y_i$).
$Y_i$ and $Z_i$ have the same distribution for $i \in \{1,2\}$ (since all $X_i, Y_i, Z_i$ random variables have distribution $Bern(1/2)$).

However
\begin{align}
&\{X_1\leq Z_1\} = \{B\leq 1-B\} = \{B=0\}\\
&\{X_2\leq Z_2\} = \{1-B\leq B\} = \{B=1\}=\{B=0\}^c
\end{align}
So the events $\{X_1\leq Z_1\}$ and $\{X_2\leq Z_2\}$ are disjoint, in fact, they are complements of each other. This fact depends only on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$, regardless of the probability measure. So using the same $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$, the same functions $B, X_i, Y_i, Z_i$, but considering any other probability measure $\tilde{P}:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow[0,1]$ we have (by the fact that the probabilities of complemenatary events sum to 1):
$$ \tilde{P}[X_1\leq Z_1]+\tilde{P}[X_2\leq Z_2]=1$$
Therefore, we cannot have both $\tilde{P}[X_1\leq Z_1]=1$ and $\tilde{P}[X_2\leq Z_2]=1$.
